# $C([0,\infty))$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, function-spaces

In many books (e.g. Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve) the fact that $C([0,\infty)):=\{f\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$ endowed with the metric
$$
d(f,g) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\min\{\sup_{t\in[0,k]}|f(t)-g(t)|,1\}
$$
is a complete separable metric space, is left as an exercise for the reader. I am certainly struggling to show that the space is separable. I would be grateful for any reference or hint.

Comment: Hint: $C([0, 1])$ with supremum-norm is separable, and $d(f, g) \leq \|f - g\|_{[0, k]} + 2^{-k+1}$.

Comment: Did you atleast guess what could be a countable dense set? There is a very natural choice.

Comment: @geetha290krm On a compact interval I would take the polynomials with rational coefficients.

Comment: Same set works here too.